# Android: ListView like RetailMeNot app

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

Just came across this app [RetailMeNot Coupons](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whaleshark.retailmenot&hl=en). The list view used is custom and looks pretty cool. Initially, the list show smaller image of a child-item. As the user scrolls up, the child item expands fully to reveal a bigger image.

Out of curiosity, I plan to build a similar list-view in a test app.
I am sure this is a custom list-view, has anyone seen a library or implementation of a similar list-view?

[image: List Position 1]

[image: List Position 2]

[image: List Position 3]

Comment: May be it's a hybrid app.

Comment: Its not Hybrid app its anroid's native app @Apurva

Comment: @Faheem did you implement this?

Comment: @Faheem Kalsekar Have you done this listview?

Comment: Could you achieve this effect?

Comment: it's wonderful Have you done this effect?

Comment: Nope. I couldn't achieve it. Are you guys looking for same Parallax Listview effect?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this library

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

May be some customization on this library can help you.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried directly working with listviewscroll.

Is not perfect but is a start

```
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getListView().setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            for (int j=0; j<visibleItemCount; j++) {
                if(absListView.getChildAt(j).getClass() == FrameLayout.class) {
                    FrameLayout item = (FrameLayout) absListView.getChildAt(j);
                    String result = "";
                    if (item != null) {
                        RelativeLayout relative1 = (RelativeLayout) item.getChildAt(0);
                        ImageView promoImage = (ImageView) relative1.getChildAt(0);
                        View promoOverlay = (View) relative1.getChildAt(1);
                        RelativeLayout relative2 = (RelativeLayout) relative1.getChildAt(2);
                        ImageView brandImage = (ImageView) relative2.getChildAt(0);
                        TextView promoText = (TextView) relative2.getChildAt(1);
                        item.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(item.getWidth(), (int) minHeight));
                        if (item.getTop() < maxHeight) {
                            if (item.getTop() >= 0) {
                                float topPercent = item.getTop() / maxHeight;
                                float newHeight = minHeight + ((maxHeight - minHeight) * (1 - topPercent));
                                if (newHeight <= maxHeight) {
                                    item.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(item.getWidth(), (int) newHeight));
                                    promoOverlay.setAlpha(topPercent / 2);
                                } else {
                                    item.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(item.getWidth(), (int) maxHeight));
                                    if (item.getTop() > 0) {
                                        promoOverlay.setAlpha(0.5f);
                                    } else {
                                        promoOverlay.setAlpha(0f);
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                float topPercent = (-item.getTop()) / maxHeight;
                                float newHeight = maxHeight - ((maxHeight - minHeight) * (topPercent));
                                if (newHeight >= minHeight) {
                                    item.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(item.getWidth(), (int) newHeight));
                                    promoOverlay.setAlpha(topPercent / 2);
                                } else {
                                    item.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(item.getWidth(), (int) minHeight));
                                }
                                promoOverlay.setAlpha(0);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (item.getTop() > 0) {
                                item.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(item.getWidth(), (int) minHeight));
                                promoOverlay.setAlpha(0.5f);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```